# Unable to match class for part: 'Lrx/Observable;' (unknown error)

Tags: java, android, backendless

hey guys am trying to execute the below method but am getting an error which says:

`Unable to match class for part: 'Lrx/Observable;`

my method:

```
public void SendNote(){


    titleStr = etxtTitle.getText().toString();


// saving objects
    NotesRealmClass notesRealmClass = new NotesRealmClass();
    notesRealmClass.setTitle("try");

// save object asynchronously
Backendless.Persistence.save(notesRealmClass, new AsyncCallback<NotesRealmClass>() {
    public void handleResponse(NotesRealmClass note) {
        // new Contact instance has been saved
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Successfully posted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + fault.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // an error has occurred, the error code can be retrieved with fault.getCode()
}
}); }
```

here am trying to save an Object into [Backendless](http://backendless.com) Server but am getting this error, any one can explain me what this error is trying to tell ?? i searched around but didnt get anything yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it turns out that its a fault in realm , according to this https://www.bountysource.com/issues/29233605-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-rx-observable-in-0-87-0 , for fixing it we just have to put compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.16' in our grade file